# When does the void start in the overworld? - minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build something under the floor of either the nether or the overworld.

I know that you can survive in the top n number of layers but don't know the exact Number.

How much space will I have to work with. I need about 6 blocks of depth.

Also if it is less than 5 how can I extend this?

The wiki doesn't have an exact figure for these dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The void starts under layer 0 which is typically the bedrock layer (in superflat worlds and with mods or map editors you can remove the bedrock layer).

You cannot build under layer 0 because each chunk only goes from layer 0 to 255. You might be able to survive there as a player, but you won't be able to place any type of blocks.

If you want to have the effect of building in the void you can use a map editor like [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to move some of the bedrock up somewhere (don't forget to remove a block of bedrock or two so you can get in there!).

Comment: I have placed blocks maybe i had settings or a mod installed and i didn't realise it had that effect

Comment: It could be I suppose, I recall a older mod that might have done that. I've edited in a way to achieve the effect of building in the void.